# Sort entire nested object by property in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I would like to loop through a deeply nested object, and sort each level based on a property. In this case its `id`

Here's my object (there will me more levels, I just added 3 levels here for readability):

```
const myObj = [
  {
    id: 15,
    children: [
      {
        id: 9,
        children: [
          {
            id: 4,
            children: []
          },
          {
            id: 1,
            children: []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        children: [
          {
            id: 35,
            children: [
              {
                id: 12,
                children: []
              },
              {
                id: 8,
                children: []
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            id: 30,
            children: [],
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    children: [
      {
        id: 9,
        children: []
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        children: []
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

Here's the desired output:

```
const myObj = [
  {
    id: 2,
    children: [
      {
        id: 3,
        children: []
      },
      {
        id: 9,
        children: []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 15,
    children: [
      {
        id: 4,
        children: [
          {
            id: 30,
            children: [],
          },
          {
            id: 35,
            children: [
              {
                id: 8,
                children: []
              },
              {
                id: 12,
                children: []
              }
            ]
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 9,
        children: [
          {
            id: 1,
            children: []
          },
          {
            id: 4,
            children: []
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

And here's my attempt at sorting it:

```js
const myObj = [{id:15,children:[{id:9,children:[{id:4,children:[]},{id:1,children:[]}]},{id:4,children:[{id:35,children:[{id:12,children:[]},{id:8,children:[]}]},{id:30,children:[],}]},]},{id:2,children:[{id:9,children:[]},{id:3,children:[]},]}]

function sortByOrderIndex(obj) {
  obj.sort((a, b) => (a.orderindex > b.orderindex) ? 1 : ((b.orderindex > a.orderindex) ? -1 : 0));

  return obj;
}

function sortNestedObj(obj) {
  sortByOrderIndex(obj);

  for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    const t = obj[i];

    if (t.children.length !== 0) {
      sortNestedObj(t.children);
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }
}

console.log(sortByOrderIndex(myObj))
```

I've created a function that sorts an object, and then tried to create another object that loops through each object that has children and sort those children using the first function. And if those children have children, then sort those and so forth until a child has no children.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could recursively [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) the array and it's object's `children` like this:

```js
const myObj = [{id:15,children:[{id:9,children:[{id:4,children:[]},{id:1,children:[]}]},{id:4,children:[{id:35,children:[{id:12,children:[]},{id:8,children:[]}]},{id:30,children:[],}]},]},{id:2,children:[{id:9,children:[]},{id:3,children:[]},]}]

function sortArray(array) {
  array.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
  array.forEach(a => {
    if (a.children && a.children.length > 0)
      sortArray(a.children)
  })
  return array;
}

console.log(sortArray(myObj))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a recursive sorting function:

```js
const myObj = [{id:15,children:[{id:9,children:[{id:4,children:[]},{id:1,children:[]}]},{id:4,children:[{id:35,children:[{id:12,children:[]},{id:8,children:[]}]},{id:30,children:[],}]},]},{id:2,children:[{id:9,children:[]},{id:3,children:[]},]}]

const orderChildren = obj => {
  obj.children.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
  if (obj.children.some(o => o.children.length)) {
    obj.children.forEach(child => orderChildren(child));
  }
  return obj;
};

const myNewObj = myObj.map(o => orderChildren(o)).sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);

console.log(myNewObj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```js
const myObj = [{id: 15,children: [{id: 9,children: [{id: 4,children: []},{id: 1,children: []}]},{id: 4,children: [{id: 35,children: [{id: 12,children: []},{id: 8,children: []}]},{id: 30,children: [],}]},]},{id: 2,children: [{id: 9,children: []},{id: 3,children: []},]}];
const deepSortById = arr => (arr.forEach(a => a.children && deepSortById(a.children)), arr.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id));

const result = deepSortById(myObj);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I created generic solution for sorting nested arrays by id. My solution works with any nested array and sorts it according to `id` property. Or by any other property you specify in the method's seconds parameter.

```
function sortNestedArrays(obj, sortPropertyName) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
        if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
            obj[key].sort((a, b) => a[sortPropertyName] - b[sortPropertyName]);
        }

        if (!!obj[key] && (typeof obj[key] === 'object' || Array.isArray(obj[key]))) {
            sortNestedArrays(obj[key], sortPropertyName);
        }
    });

    return obj;
}
```

Usage is following:

```
obj = sortNestedArrays(obj, 'id');
```